# Polygon intersection with bounding box with polygon's holes intact

Tags: postgis, geojson, leaflet, geodjango

I am trying to serve GeoJSON FeatureCollection tiles with each feature's geometries trimmed to the tile boundary.

I am working on a Leaflet plugin to re-assemble the geometries. It works by building up a pool of lines for a unique feature, removing any equal lines in opposing directions, then walking any unwalked lines to recreate the linear rings.

This currently works, except I am having trouble dealing with polygon holes. When I have a polygon with a hole and generate the GeoJSON to intersect it with the tile boundary - I lose the hole information.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could keep the hole information intact on the server side, or alternatively detect this happening on the client-side?

Comment: Why don't you take the xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax for each feature and convert it directly to a bounding box polygon?

Comment: you mean [`ST_Envelope(geom)`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am using something like this:

```
ST_SimplifyPreserveTopology((ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(way, !bbox!))).geom, !pixel_width! / 2) AS way
```

...